# laravel 5.5 email-verification with josiasmontag package

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

First of all I am new to laravel. I have installed laravel 5.5 and have configured the register and login and I am trying to add email verification when a user registers.
I have pulled in composer require josiasmontag/laravel-email-verification. This is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'isEmailVerified']], function () {
('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')
}
```

and done everything but when I test it I get

when I test it I get

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','"
and it is coming from the route

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have syntax error here.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'isEmailVerified']], function () {
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

You forgot to add `Route::get('/home'` or `Route::post('/home'`

Comment: yea... it didn't even crossed my mind. thanks @user2486

Comment: now I am getting this error                                                                       
"Type error: Argument 1 passed to Lunaweb\EmailVerification\EmailVerification::createToken() must be an instance of Lunaweb\EmailVerification\Contracts\CanVerify ▶"

Comment: I am sorry it's not part of your question can you please create another question with full, details ?

Comment: ok will create it now